# JavaScript discord bot TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I am trying this JavaScript ticket code in my discord bot, but the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined` keeps showing up. I don't understand why. Could someone guide me in the correct direction?

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ticket",
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "Open a ticket!",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
      const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);
      channel.setParent("820276801652916270");
  
      channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
        SEND_MESSAGE: false,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
      });
      channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
        SEND_MESSAGE: true,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
      });
  
      const reactionMessage = await channel.send("Thank you for contacting support!");
  
      try {
        await reactionMessage.react("");
        await reactionMessage.react("⛔");
      } catch (err) {
        channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
        throw err;
      }
  
      const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
        (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
        { dispose: true }
      );
  
      collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
          case "":
            channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
            break;
          case "⛔":
            channel.send("Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!");
            setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
            break;
        }
      });
  
      message.channel
        .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
        .then((msg) => {
          setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
          setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have not defined `message` when executing your file. Could you provide us with the code that executes this file?

Comment: Yeah... do you mean one of this parts?

if(command === 'ticket'){
        client.commands.get('ticket').execute(message.args);
    }
})

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


 async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {

Answer (score 1):

Using the info in your comment, your command handler was set up incorrectly.  When you put `execute(message.args)`, the code tried to pass the `args` property of your message argument which returns `undefined`.

Instead, you should use `execute(message, args)` to properly pass in each argument for your command.